# Can I avoid or cache a `usermod` and `chown` command during docker build?

Tags: docker, file-permissions, alpine-linux

In my company, we have a common pattern of running `usermod` near the of the Dockerfile in order to get the permissions straight.

E.g.:

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm-alpine
...
COPY . .
RUN usermod -u $USER_ID www-data && chown -R www-data:www-data $COMPOSER_HOME ./
USER www-data
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

This has the benefit that the container won't run as root, yet due to cache invalidation, the command will almost always need to be triggered and it may take quite a long time during build.

I want a very quick build of my Dockerfile and whilst I can have every previous layer cached, this one as is will always need to be executed on a source file change and it may take a while depending on the amount of files for the project.

I am wondering if there is a way to avoid running `usermod` and `chown`. but if I can add the files in a certain with the permissions already in place or if this approach could already be considered best practice.

I also remember a pattern of having my hosts' user in the docker group in order to be able to have access to the files?

Besides increasing build speed, I also want to avoid injecting the host's user id.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Generally for security purposes I'd expect the application code to be owned by `root`, _not_ the `www-data` user, so that the application code can't be accidentally modified.  Similarly, you shouldn't usually need the non-root user ID in the container to match anything on the host.  I'd just delete the `RUN` line you have here.

Comment: @DavidMaze Can you please explicate this? Background is that the container also run in a local dev stack, and hence binaries such as composer need write permission in certain folders. Just deleting the the RUN statement won't suffice in this case. I have the feeling we are doing something wrong, but I have no idea on how to do it differently.

Comment: Just found out about https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/6119#issuecomment-338920866 -- will try `COPY --chown=someuser:somegroup /foo /bar` approach and post it as an answer if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Since Docker 17.09 and up one can add the `chown` flag to both `COPY` and `ADD`:

```
COPY --chown=someuser:somegroup /foo /bar
ADD --chown=someuser:somegroup /foo /bar
```

I stumbled over a [medium post by Leonid Makarov](https://medium.com/@lmakarov/the-backlash-of-chmod-chown-mv-in-your-dockerfile-f12fe08c0b55)
  and by that over an [github issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/6119), and there the solution was provided.